# MySQL Heap Table

Tags: mysql

I have learnt that table can be created with order, like adding primary key. On the other hand, heap table is unordered, as mentioned in this page: https://www.sqlshack.com/clustered-index-vs-heap.

However, seems Heap Table is Mysql only refer to table in memory. Reference: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-reference-manual/0596002653/ch07s04.html.

So does MYSQL database have any terminology for unordered table?

Please correct me if I get any wrong concepts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Oreilly link is so old that it has a syntax error.  (`TYPE=HEAP` became `ENGINE=MEMORY` about 2 decades ago.)

The default indexing of an `ENGINE=MEMORY` table is a heap.  It does not provide persistence, so it is only useful for certain temporary purposes.

For most uses, you should use `ENGINE=InnoDB` and have a `PRIMARY KEY`, which will be BTree-organized.

"Heap" is not necessarily better than "BTree".  And it is much worse in a main way: the lack of ordering.  Looking up a single row in Hash-organized table is not necessarily faster than in a BTree-organized table.  These points lead to why MySQL did not bother to implement Hash as a significant option.

Anyway, Hash is not really "unordered"; instead, let's say "hard to predict".

A table (or subquery) is technically unordered.  That is, the order of the results is *not guaranteed* unless you explicitly use `ORDER BY`.  The implementation *may* deliver rows in a predictable order.  But that is usually because the Optimizer happened to do something predictable.

To get an unordered list,

- Simply perform `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY` -- in some cases, it will ignore the BTree ordering and provide a seemingly random order.
- Or, Use `ORDER BY RAND()` to explicitly shuffle the rows.  (Note: the same query will give a different ordering each time.)

Why do you "want" an unordered table?  Seriously; if you have some goal, there may be a simple workaround.

Another thing to note:  MySQL (ENGINE=InnoDB) "clusters" the `PRIMARY KEY` with the data, thereby forcing an order on the data.  Some other engines and vendors do not do this "clustering".

For example, MySQL's deprecated ENGINE=MyISAM stores the data in the order of insertion.  The PRIMARY KEY, if present, is simply a lookup table like any secondary index.  (Caveat:  Deletes and Updates mess with the ordering.)

Answer (score 0):

One of your links is for SQL Server, the other for MySQL.
Only in-memory or temporary tables can be heap tables in MySQL because clustered indexes are assigned automatically in MySQL.